# Wine programs use different audio device from system

Tags: audio, wine

My laptop, running Linux Mint 18.3 with wine version 1.6.2, is set to use a headset as its output device.  When configuring wine's audio settings, the "Test Sound" button sends audio to the correct device.  However, none of the programs I run with wine respect the configuration; outputting to the laptop's built-in speakers.

Is there a way to correct the routing of sound from programs running with wine?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. I uninstalled the supplied version of Wine, which is quite outdated, and installed fresh new stable using these instructions: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu.
Now works like a charm.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be as useful.  Could you include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading?  Thanks.